# ProtoContract breaks XmlMediaTypeFormatter behavior

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, xmlserializer

I have an ASP.NET web application that needs to take requests in form of JSON, XML and ProtoBuf. In order to have ProtoBuf working I need to annotate the DTO with [ProtoContract] but as soon as I do this, XML stops working.

I can isolate the problem very much to the [ProtoContract]. I made this small test application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ser = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter();
        ser.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"With ProtoContract: {ser.CanReadType(typeof(Foo))}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Without ProtoContract: {ser.CanReadType(typeof(Foo1))}");
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(0)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo1
{
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }
}
```

The output is:

```
With ProtoContract: False
Without ProtoContract: True
```

The observation is pretty clear, as soon as the attribute is added XmlSerializer  can't read the object anymore. Did someone experience a similiar behavior? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very interesting - I don't know how it is doing that, but I will be looking in reflector this evening!

However, the fix is simple in this case:

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public string Bar { get; set; }
```

Oddly, the reason I knew to check this is that `0` is never a legal tag in protobuf, but I am very intrigued that `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` would *care*.

Update: the reason is because  of how `XmlSerializer` accesses the attributes on the object, but swallows the exception to mean "nope, can't do that". It falls victim to your actual problem; try:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
```

You should see:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Foo'. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: tag
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoMemberAttribute..ctor(Int32 tag) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoMemberAttribute.cs:line 47
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
```

and so on, which is simply `ProtoMembmerAttribute` complaining about an illegal tag.

Comment: Very interesting. I am not really seeing the relation between the wrong ProtoMember tag and the XmlSerializer but this solves my problem. Great, thanks!

Comment: @Matthias `XmlSerializer` obtains the attributes via a particular API that materializes each, using the attribute's constructor etc for each; in this case, because the data is misconfigured, the attribute's constructor throws an exception. `XmlSerializer` swallows this exception, simply saying "no". There are ways `XmlSerializer` could have avoided this problem, but I don't see it being changed.